# How to access a Dockerized R image trough Lambda|API Gateway?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr, plumber

the first version of this question may not be as clear as I would like just because there's many parts and the problem is in one part of the process.

as easy as I can:
I have a dockerized R application exposed to http access by plumber and I want to have it in aws lambda.

The Dockerfile is very simple:

```
FROM rstudio/plumber:latest

WORKDIR /opt/ml

# system libraries of general use
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    wget \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev\
    libsodium-dev \
    ca-certificates

# r pkgs (https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/docker.html)
RUN R -e "install.packages('renv', repos = c(CRAN = 'https://cloud.r-project.org'))"

# renv (https://nicd.ncl.ac.uk/blog/posts/deploying-model-predictions-using-plumber-and-docker/)
COPY . .
RUN R -e "renv::restore()" # uncomment to create docker image with renv

# plumber
ENTRYPOINT ["Rscript", "run_plumber.R"] # uncomment to create docker image with renv
EXPOSE 8080/tcp
```

```
docker build -t image-name:0.0.1 .
docker run --name sandbox --restart=always -p 8080:8080 -v C:\Users\User\Downloads\aws_s3:/data image-name:0.0.1
```

when I run this commands I get a container that I can access with curl like this:

```
curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8080/functionName?param1=/data/archive.json&param2=/data/archive.csv"
```

or as docs suggest, I have this function

```
# plumber.R

#* Echo back the input
#* @param msg The message to echo
#* @get /echo
function(msg="") {
  list(msg = paste0("The message is: '", msg, "'"))
}
```

and I get the result by (this is just to confirm that the workflow works

```
curl -X GET"http://127.0.0.1:8080/echo?msg=hi"
```

Everything until here is okay; once the image is tagged and pushed to ECR and a lambda function is created on top of it and I access it through API Gateway

In the API Gateway I set a Resource and a method, the resource is the name of the function "echo" as the curl and function specifies; Once deployed I know the plumber library is exposing in port 8080

When I call my function through the API Gateway: I get this log in cloud watch:

```
Error: failed to create directory at path '/home/sbx_user1051/.local/share/renv'
In addition: Warning message:
In dir.create(rownames(info), recursive = TRUE) :
cannot create dir '/home/sbx_user1051/.local', reason 'No such file or directory'
Traceback (most recent calls last):
19: source("renv/activate.R")
18: withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
17: eval(ei, envir)
16: eval(ei, envir)
15: local(...)
14: eval.parent(substitute(eval(quote(expr), envir)))
13: eval(expr, p)
12: eval(expr, p)
11: eval(quote(...), new.env())
10: eval(quote(...), new.env())
9: renv_bootstrap_load(project, libpath, version)
8: renv::load(project)
7: renv_load_renviron(project)
6: renv_paths_root(".Renviron")
5: Sys.getenv("RENV_PATHS_ROOT", unset = NA) %NA% renv_paths_root_default()
4: renv_paths_root_default()
3: ensure_directory(path)
2: stopf("failed to create directory at path '%s'", rownames(info))
1: stop(sprintf(fmt, ...), call. = call.)
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `/home/sbx_user1051/.local` is not writable, see also [docker-lambda #103](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda/issues/103). In your Dockerfile right before the **renv** part, set `RENV_PATHS_ROOT` to a directory for which the default user has write access in order to bypass the error, eg.

```sh
ENV RENV_PATHS_ROOT="/tmp/.local/share/renv"
# ENV RENV_PATHS_ROOT="${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/.local/share/renv" # works similarly
```

See also the [**renv** docs](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/reference/paths.html) for further details on path customization. In addition, note that without the `use.cache` being disabled in `renv/settings.dcf`, you might run into L2 cache size issues on AWS Lambda:

[image: l2_cache_size]

Comment: Yes, indeed it's a permissions error, defining a path inside the /tmp folder does solve the issue.
Thank you!

Comment: I am trying to go through this process myself. I'm having a bit of a challenge configuring the lambda function. How do you ensure that Lambda or the API Gateway goes to the correct endpoint from the plumber API?

I've deployed the container via ECR, imported the swagger docs, and added the container image to Lambda then added Lambda in the API gateway

Comment: @thus__ that requires some docker port mapping, but what I did to go around the plumber option is to execute R through python, so I configure the dockerized lambda function to use subprocess and this way I execute Popen on the R script and capture the response in stdout.